# MaskedTextBox Extended Wpf Toolkit

Tags: nullreferenceexception, mask, maskedtextbox

I have a problem with MaskedTextBox that comes from Extended Wpf Toolkit. So, when i use it instead of TextBox there is an error - Null Reference Exception. Then i searched the reason and finally found it. When i use MaskedTextBox with Mask Property

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox
      Name="txtMessage"
      Value="{Binding Message, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      IncludeLiteralsInValue="False"
      Mask="(000)000-00-00"
      TextBoxBase.TextChanged="txtMessage_TextChanged" 
      ValueDataType="{x:Type s:String}">
```

it causes `Null Reference Exception` because `DataContext` of `UserControl` is `null`, but I don't know why, the `Constructor` of `UserControl` has something like this:

```
  editModel = new EditViewModel();
  DataContext = editModel;
```

And `editModel` is `null`. But When I delete `Mask` property everything works fine. Can you help me pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem** was that `Mask` Property of `MaskedTextBox` is bind to a `Text` Property of `TextBox`. So when Xaml page generates, app tries bind `Mask` property to the `Message`, but in this moment `ViewModel` is not created and so occurs a 'NullReferenceException'. 

**The Solution** is that you must set the `Mask` property of `MaskedTextBox` not in Xaml, and after declaring your `ViewModel`.

`editModel = new EditViewModel();
 DataContext = editModel;
 txtMessage.Mask = "(000)00-000-00-00";`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error linked to missed property ValieDataType, after I set up this property in XAML all work fine. No need to setup mask via code.